# How to handle blank dates sent as parameters to Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm writing a webapp where there are dates to be sent to a Servlet and I want to send some blank dates and based on these dates I want to build a query. But here My problem is when I pass the parameters i.e. the dates it's working fine, And when I send blank parameters it is throwing me the below error.

```
Start date got is  and end date is //Here I'm checking the output
Unparseable date: "" servlet Errotr
```

When I give in the dates it shows in console as 
`Start date got is (TheStartDateValue) and end date is (TheEndDateValue)`
 and there is no exception (since the dates are parsed). And below is my code.

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            /* Date Start */
            String startDateStr = request.getParameter("startDate");
            String endDateStr = request.getParameter("endDate");
            System.out.println("Start date got is " + startDateStr + " and end date is " + endDateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date startParsedDate = null, endParsedDate = null;
            String startDate = null, endDate = null;
            if (!startDateStr.equals(null) || !startDateStr.equals("")) {
                startParsedDate = sdf.parse(startDateStr);
                startDate = print.format(startParsedDate);
            }
            if (!endDateStr.equals(null) || !endDateStr.equals("")) {
                endParsedDate = sdf.parse(endDateStr);
                endDate = print.format(endParsedDate);
            }

            System.out.println(startDate + " value and " + endDate);
            /* Date End */
            DataDao dataDao = new DataDao();
            ArrayList<UserBean> list = dataDao.getFrameWork(startDate, endDate);
            String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(searchList);
            System.out.println("servlet Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " servlet Errotr");
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to handle the `startDateStr` and `startDateStr`to chweck if the input values are `null` or having some value using the below block in my above code.

```
if (!startDateStr.equals(null) || !startDateStr.equals("")) {
        startParsedDate = sdf.parse(startDateStr);
        startDate = print.format(startParsedDate);
}
if (!endDateStr.equals(null) || !endDateStr.equals("")) {
        endParsedDate = sdf.parse(endDateStr);
        endDate = print.format(endParsedDate);
}
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in condition `!startDateStr.equals(null) || !startDateStr.equals("")`, you should change it to `startDateStr != null && !startDateStr.equals("")` and the same problem is in second condition.

Comment: Hey This is working awesome, but I've a quick question, for `String` we are supposed to use equals instead of `=`, please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @user3872094, you use `equals` for content equality and `=` for reference equality (in your case comparing to the `null` reference)